# Why Kenny sleeping with the gun?

Tags: plot-explanation, analysis, a-single-man

In Single Man (2009), in the final scene where George finds Kenny sleeping with his gun under the covers he takes the gun silently & locks it in drawer.

[image]

Why is Kenny sleeping with the gun?

Is he afraid of George?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why is Kenny sleeping with the gun?

George had been contemplating suicide by shooting himself. Kenny knew that George had been planning to kill himself so **he takes the gun to keep it from George**.

As it turns out meeting Kenny changes George's mind so, having found the gun, he locks it away.

> George passes out and wakes up alone in bed with Kenny asleep in another room. George gets up and while watching Kenny discovers that he had fallen asleep holding George's gun, taken from the desktop, **to keep George from committing suicide.** George locks the gun away, burns his suicide notes and in a closing voiceover explains how he has rediscovered the ability "to feel, rather than think".
>
> <sup>[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_Single_Man)</sup>